# wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'application' throwing 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I've encountered a strange error using wicked_pdf.

I've never had the same issue on my mac,
but on my production centos 6.6 vps, it throws **404 error** on the line:

```
wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
```

I'm using

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 0.11.0'
```

I've tried to add `application.css.scss` or `application.css` into `initializer/assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.1'
# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(*.svg *.eot *.woff *.ttf *.gif *.png *.ico)
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(application.css *.js *.css *.js.coffee)
```

but still does not work,

Anyone have any clue what can be done?

On my ubuntu 14 server used as development machine,

```
wicked_pdf_image_tag object.file1.file.path
```

seems to cause the pdf generator to hang.

I've  commented off it, it works. And I've checked that the path is correct.

The problem will also persists with image_tag helper, but works fine when displayed in html format.

**full trace showing:**

> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:353:in
>   `open_http'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:724:in`
>   buffer_open'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:210:in
>   `block in open_loop'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:208:in`
>   catch'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:208:in
>   `open_loop'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:149:in`
>   open_uri'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:704:in
>   `open'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:34:in`
>   open' wicked_pdf (0.11.0) lib/wicked_pdf/wicked_pdf_helper.rb:111:in
>   `read_from_uri' wicked_pdf (0.11.0)
>   lib/wicked_pdf/wicked_pdf_helper.rb:100:in`read_asset' wicked_pdf
>   (0.11.0) lib/wicked_pdf/wicked_pdf_helper.rb:40:in `block in
>   wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag' wicked_pdf (0.11.0)
>   lib/wicked_pdf/wicked_pdf_helper.rb:38:in`collect' wicked_pdf
>   (0.11.0) lib/wicked_pdf/wicked_pdf_helper.rb:38:in
>   `wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag' app/views/layouts/pdf.html.slim:5:in`
>   _app_views_layouts_pdf_html_slim___1321156534865974876_43089880'
>   actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in
>   render' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in`instrument' actionview
>   (4.1.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument' actionview
>   (4.1.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in`render' actionview (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:67:in
>   `render_with_layout' actionview (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in`render_template'
>   actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in
>   `render' actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in`
>   render_template' actionview (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render' actionview (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in`_render_template' actionpack
>   (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in
>   `_render_template' actionview (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in`render_to_body' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
>   actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in`
>   render_to_body' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:43:in `render_to_string'
>   actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:21:in`
>   render_to_string' wicked_pdf (0.11.0)
>   lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:34:in `render_to_string_with_wicked_pdf'
>   wicked_pdf (0.11.0) lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:61:in`make_pdf'
>   wicked_pdf (0.11.0) lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:32:in
>   `render_to_string_with_wicked_pdf'
>   app/controllers/concerns/has_pdf_response.rb:15:in`respond_to_pdf'
>   app/controllers/quotations_controller.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in
>   show' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:258:in`call' actionpack
>   (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:258:in
>   `respond_to' app/controllers/quotations_controller.rb:20:in`show'
>   actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in
>   `send_action' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in`process_action' actionpack
>   (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in`block in process_action'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in`call'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in
>   halting' activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`
>   call' activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in
>   `block in halting' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in`call' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in
>   halting_and_conditional' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in`call' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in`call'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in
>   halting' activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`
>   call' activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in
>   `block in halting' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`call' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`call'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in
>   halting' activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in`
>   call' activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in
>   `block in halting' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`call' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`call'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in
>   halting' activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in`
>   call' activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in
>   `block in halting' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`call' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`call'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in
>   halting' activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`
>   call' activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in
>   `block in halting' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`call' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in`call'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in
>   `run_callbacks' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in`process_action' actionpack
>   (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in`block in
>   process_action' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
>   activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in
>   `instrument' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
>   activerecord (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in`
>   process_action' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process' actionview (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in`process' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in
>   action' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in`call' actionpack
>   (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
>   actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in`
>   call' actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in
>   `block in call' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in`each' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in`call' rack-pjax
>   (0.8.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call' warden (1.2.3)
>   lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`block in call' warden (1.2.3)
>   lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch' warden (1.2.3)
>   lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`call' rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in
>   `call' rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in`call' rack
>   (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call' remotipart (1.2.1)
>   lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in`call' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in`
>   call' rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
>   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in`call' actionpack
>   (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
>   activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in`call'
>   activerecord (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in
>   `call' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in`block in call'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in
>   `run_callbacks' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call' actionpack
>   (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in`
>   call' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
>   railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app' railties
>   (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call' activesupport
>   (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
>   activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`
>   tagged' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged' railties (4.1.6)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call' activesupport (4.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in`
>   call' rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call' actionpack (4.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in`call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call' railties (4.1.6)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in`call' railties (4.1.6)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call' passenger (4.0.56)
>   lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in`
>   process_request' passenger (4.0.56)
>   lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in
>   `accept_and_process_next_request' passenger (4.0.56)
>   lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in`
>   main_loop' passenger (4.0.56)
>   lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:455:in `block (3 levels) in
>   start_threads'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turn out that ive pointed an absolute path to my image when i called 
**wicked_pdf_image_tag**
the function actually points to 
    root_path.join('**public**', '**images**')

the solution is to either create a new method or just use this code:
    image_tag "file://absolute_path_to_img_here", options

[http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mileszs/wicked_pdf/WickedPdfHelper%3Awicked_pdf_image_tag][1]

Comment: I had similar i upload images in my system so it was storing in `public/system`  but now i had change storage and now file is uploading to s3 bucket. i use aws load balancer so everytime new instace generate i is always giving me error as you mentioned. can you suggest me how to overcome this issue ?